# Click number to call in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dial a phone number with an access code programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456395/dial-a-phone-number-using-ios)

I am creating an iPhone application for a company. In one of the pages, I included the company's phone number. However, I want the number on the interface to be able to dial in one click.

For example, the number I have typed in the back-end would be made available to call on the application page instead of a text showing the number. I want to make it dial-able through a click on the number.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456395/dial-a-phone-number-using-ios

Comment: *ring ring* Hello? Is Xcode 4 there?

Answer (score 1):

Place your phone number in `UITextView` readonly instance and make it auto-detect phone numbers with `dataDetectorTypes` property.