# How to make URL/Phone-clickable UILabel?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, url, uilabel

I want to create a clickable label on my app leading me to a Safari webpage. I also want the user to be able to phone the numbers only by clicking on them ?

Thanks for your advices

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create tap-able "links" in the NSAttributedText of a UILabel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256887/create-tap-able-links-in-the-nsattributedtext-of-a-uilabel)

Answer (score 143, accepted):

You can use a `UITextView` and select Detection for Links, Phone Numbers and other things in the inspector.

Comment: I have a self resizing label which can accommodate N lines of text. How can I make the links in this label clickable without implementing UITextView.

Comment: @bibscy then you can use the NSAttributedText. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256887/create-tap-able-links-in-the-nsattributedstring-of-a-uilabel

Answer (score 100):

Use `UITextView` instead of `UILabel` and it has a property to convert your text to hyperlink.

#### Objective-C:

```
yourTextView.editable = NO;
yourTextView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
```

#### Swift:

```
yourTextView.editable = false; 
yourTextView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypes.All;
```

This will detect links automatically.

See [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatadetectortypes) for details.

Comment: this colors the link blue and underlines it, but does seem to make it clickable, at least on iOS 7.

Comment: Swift code:
yourTextView.editable = false;
yourTextView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypes.All;

Comment: the question is about UILabel, not UITextView.

Answer (score 30):

https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel

That's definitely what you need. You can also apply attributes for your label, like underline, and apply different colors to it. Just check the instructions for clickable urls.

Mainly, you do something like the following:

```
NSRange range = [label.text rangeOfString:@"me"];
[label addLinkToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://github.com/mattt/"] withRange:range]; // Embedding a custom link in a substring
```

Answer (score 12):

You can make a custom UIButton and setText what ever you want and add a method with that.

```
UIButton *sampleButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[sampleButton setFrame:CGRectMake(kLeftMargin, 10, self.view.bounds.size.width - kLeftMargin - kRightMargin, 52)];
[sampleButton setTitle:@"URL Text" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[sampleButton setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20]];


[sampleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:sampleButton];


-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
  // open url
}
```

Comment: Setting the font is now done by: button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:size];

Answer (score 11):

If you want this to be handled by UILabel and not UITextView, you can make UILabel subclass, like this one:

```
class LinkedLabel: UILabel {

fileprivate let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
fileprivate let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: CGSize.zero)
fileprivate var textStorage: NSTextStorage?


override init(frame aRect:CGRect){
    super.init(frame: aRect)
    self.initialize()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.initialize()
}

func initialize(){

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(LinkedLabel.handleTapOnLabel))
    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

override var attributedText: NSAttributedString?{
    didSet{
        if let _attributedText = attributedText{
            self.textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: _attributedText)

            self.layoutManager.addTextContainer(self.textContainer)
            self.textStorage?.addLayoutManager(self.layoutManager)

            self.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0;
            self.textContainer.lineBreakMode = self.lineBreakMode;
            self.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = self.numberOfLines;
        }

    }
}

func handleTapOnLabel(tapGesture:UITapGestureRecognizer){

    let locationOfTouchInLabel = tapGesture.location(in: tapGesture.view)
    let labelSize = tapGesture.view?.bounds.size
    let textBoundingBox = self.layoutManager.usedRect(for: self.textContainer)
    let textContainerOffset = CGPoint(x: ((labelSize?.width)! - textBoundingBox.size.width) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.x, y: ((labelSize?.height)! - textBoundingBox.size.height) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.y)

    let locationOfTouchInTextContainer = CGPoint(x: locationOfTouchInLabel.x - textContainerOffset.x, y: locationOfTouchInLabel.y - textContainerOffset.y)
    let indexOfCharacter = self.layoutManager.characterIndex(for: locationOfTouchInTextContainer, in: self.textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)


    self.attributedText?.enumerateAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, in: NSMakeRange(0, (self.attributedText?.length)!), options: NSAttributedString.EnumerationOptions(rawValue: UInt(0)), using:{
        (attrs: Any?, range: NSRange, stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) in

        if NSLocationInRange(indexOfCharacter, range){
            if let _attrs = attrs{

                UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: _attrs as! String)!)
            }
        }
    })

}}
```

This class was made by reusing code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28519273/745161). In order to make attributed strings check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18518339/745161). And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5456573/745161) you can find how to make phone urls.

Answer (score 7):

Use this i liked it so much since creates link with blue color to particular text only not on whole label text: [FRHyperLabel](https://github.com/null09264/FRHyperLabel)

[image: Smartly applying hyperlink on Terms of Use]

To do:

1. Download from above link and copy `FRHyperLabel.h`, `FRHyperLabel.m` to your project.
2. Drag drop `UILabel` in your `Storyboard` and define custom class name to `FRHyperLabel` in identify inspector as shown in image.

[image]

3. Connect your UILabel from storyboard to your viewController.h file

`@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet FRHyperLabel *label;`

4. Now in your viewController.m file add following code.

`NSString *string = @"By uploading I agree to the Terms of Use";
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleHeadline]};

```
_label.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:string attributes:attributes];
[_label setFont:[_label.font fontWithSize:13.0]];

[_label setLinkForSubstring:@"Terms of Use" withLinkHandler:^(FRHyperLabel *label, NSString *substring){
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
}];`
```

5. And run it.

Answer (score 5):

Use UITextView instead of UILabel and it has a property to convert your text to hyperlink

Swift code:

```
yourTextView.editable = false
yourTextView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypes.All
//or
yourTextView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypes.PhoneNumber
//or
yourTextView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypes.Link
```

Comment: the question how to use in UILabel, rather than TextViews. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
extension UITapGestureRecognizer {

    func didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: UILabel, inRange targetRange: NSRange) -> Bool {

        let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
        let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: CGSize.zero)
        let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: label.attributedText!)

        // Configure layoutManager and textStorage
        layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
        textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)

        // Configure textContainer
        textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0
        textContainer.lineBreakMode = label.lineBreakMode
        textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = label.numberOfLines
        textContainer.size = label.bounds.size

        // main code
        let locationOfTouchInLabel = self.location(in: label)

        let indexOfCharacter = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: locationOfTouchInLabel, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)
        let indexOfCharacterRange = NSRange(location: indexOfCharacter, length: 1)
        let indexOfCharacterRect = layoutManager.boundingRect(forGlyphRange: indexOfCharacterRange, in: textContainer)
        let deltaOffsetCharacter = indexOfCharacterRect.origin.x + indexOfCharacterRect.size.width

        if locationOfTouchInLabel.x > deltaOffsetCharacter {
            return false
        } else {
            return NSLocationInRange(indexOfCharacter, targetRange)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use **NSMutableAttributedString**?

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Want to learn iOS? Just visit developer.apple.com!")
        attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: "https://developer.apple.com", range: NSRange(location: 30, length: 50))

        myView.attributedText = attributedString
```

You can find more details [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring)

Comment: I just tried today to make a call from UILabel and above code does not work. I have replaced https://dev.appl.com with tel://1234567. May be this answer needs to be updated.

Answer (score -3):

Swift 4.0 possible solution using UIButton

```
     phoneButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: view.frame.width * 0, y: view.frame.height * 0.1, width: view.frame.width * 1, height: view.frame.height * 0.05))
     phoneButton.setTitle("333-333-3333", for: .normal )
     phoneButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 0 / 255, green: 0 / 255, blue: 238 / 255, alpha: 1.0), for: .normal)
     phoneButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.callPhone), for: .touchUpInside )

     @objc func callPhone(){

         UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:"tel://3333333333")!, options: [:] , completionHandler: nil)


    }
```