# How can I concatenate NSAttributedStrings?

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

I need to search some strings and set some attributes prior to merging the strings, so having NSStrings -> Concatenate them -> Make NSAttributedString is not an option, is there any way to concatenate attributedString to another attributedString?

Comment: It is ridiculous how difficult this *still* is in August of 2016.

Comment: Even in 2018...

Comment: still in 2019 ;)

Comment: still in 2020 ...

Comment: Still in November 2020 ;)

Comment: Ah... two weeks before 2021! Merry Christmas all of us ;)

Comment: Hopefully things change in 2021 ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Still in 2021 March

Comment: Still 2021 April hahha

Comment: Still 2021 June XD

Comment: This really is a joke! (Aug 2021)

Comment: November 2021, alright this is ridiculous!

Comment: March 2022, the tradition remains

Comment: August 2022, yet... xD

Comment: Mandatory Check In - Nov'2022 it continues..... xD

Comment: and still in Mar 2023

Comment: Happy and hopeful 2024

Answer (score 223, accepted):

I'd recommend you use a single mutable attributed string a @Linuxios suggested, and here's another example of that:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];

NSString *plainString = // ...
NSDictionary *attributes = // ... a dictionary with your attributes.
NSAttributedString *newAttString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:plainString attributes:attributes];

[mutableAttString appendAttributedString:newAttString];
```

However, just for the sake of getting all the options out there, you could also create a single mutable attributed string, made from a formatted NSString containing the input strings already put together. You could then use `addAttributes: range:` to add the attributes after the fact to the ranges containing the input strings. I recommend the former way though.

Comment: Why do you recommend appending strings instead of adding attributes?

Answer (score 108):

If you're using Swift, you can just overload the `+` operator so that you can concatenate them in the same way you concatenate normal strings:

```
// concatenate attributed strings
func + (left: NSAttributedString, right: NSAttributedString) -> NSAttributedString
{
    let result = NSMutableAttributedString()
    result.append(left)
    result.append(right)
    return result
}
```

Now you can concatenate them just by adding them:

```
let helloworld = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello ") + NSAttributedString(string: "World")
```

Comment: but result is mutable! it doesn't make sense for types!

Comment: the mutable class is a subtype of the immutable class.

Comment: so I can cast result to mutable counterpart and get no error?

Comment: You can use the mutable subtype in any context that expects the immutable parent type but not vice versa. You may want to review subclassing and inheritance.

Comment: it was sarcasm. again, you should not return mutable subtype in immutable parent context in case of security. It doesn't make sense that you return 'hidden' mutable object in immutable context. Please, review immutable/mutable contexts and purposes of each one

Comment: Yes, you should do a defensive copy if you want to be defensive. (Not sarcasm.)

Comment: If you really want to return NSAttributedString, then perhaps this would work: `return NSAttributedString(attributedString: result)`

Comment: Swift 3: result.append(left)    - where do you declare such an overload? Is there a standard place where to do it? Seems weird if it's just randomly in the file you just happen to be in...

Comment: @n13 I would create a folder called `Helpers` or `Extensions` and put this function in a file named `NSAttributedString+Concatenate.swift`.

Answer (score 42):

Swift 3:  Simply create a NSMutableAttributedString and append the attributed strings to them.

```
let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()

let boldAttribute = [
    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "GothamPro-Medium", size: 13)!,
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: Constants.defaultBlackColor
]

let regularAttribute = [
    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Gotham Pro", size: 13)!,
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: Constants.defaultBlackColor
]

let boldAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Warning: ", attributes: boldAttribute)
let regularAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "All tasks within this project will be deleted.  If you're sure you want to delete all tasks and this project, type DELETE to confirm.", attributes: regularAttribute)
mutableAttributedString.append(boldAttributedString)
mutableAttributedString.append(regularAttributedString)

descriptionTextView.attributedText = mutableAttributedString
```

swift5 upd:

```
    let captionAttribute = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.font: Font.captionsRegular,
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.appGray
    ]
```

Answer (score 28):

Try this:

```
NSMutableAttributedString* result = [astring1 mutableCopy];
[result appendAttributedString:astring2];
```

Where `astring1` and `astring2` are `NSAttributedString`s.

Comment: Or `[[aString1 mutableCopy] appendAttributedString: aString2]`.

Comment: @JWWalker your 'oneliner' is corrupted. you can't get this "concatenation" result because appendAttributedString doesn't return string. Same story with dictionaries

Comment: @gaussblurinc: good point, of course your criticism also applies to the answer we're commenting on.  It should be `NSMutableAttributedString* aString3 = [aString1 mutableCopy]; [aString3 appendAttributedString: aString2];`.

Comment: @gaussblurinc, JWalker: Corrected the answer.

Comment: @Linuxios, also, you return `result` as `NSMutableAttributedString`. it is not what author want to see. `stringByAppendingString` - this method will be good

Comment: @gaussblurinc: The original post isn't clear enough for us to know that, and I don't really see a problem with this method.

Comment: @Linuxios, `concatenate attributedStrings to another attributedString` <- no word about `mutable` or something else. Also, author said about `merge` two strings to get `NSAttributedString` ( not an option in case of lost attributes ). So, concatenate `attributesStrings` and get `NSAttributedString`

Comment: @gaussblurinc: Unless I'm misunderstanding inheritance in Obj-c, a mutable attributed string can be used anywhere a normal one can.

Comment: @Linuxios this means that your approach has potential problems in security/stability. Immutable objects are better, because they can't be changed by third-party person. For example, all properties of NSString type should be have copy attribute, because they should not be changed by anyone who has a pointer to them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94962/discussion-between-linuxios-and-gaussblurinc).

Answer (score 17):

**2020 | SWIFT 5.1:**

You're able to add 2 `NSMutableAttributedString` by the following way:

```
let concatenated = NSAttrStr1.append(NSAttrStr2)
```

Another way works with `NSMutableAttributedString` and `NSAttributedString` both:

```
[NSAttrStr1, NSAttrStr2].joinWith(separator: "")
```

---

Another way is....

```
var full = NSAttrStr1 + NSAttrStr2 + NSAttrStr3
```

and:

```
var full = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "hello ")
// NSAttrStr1 == 1


full += NSAttrStr1 // "hello 1"       
full += " world"   // "hello 1 world"
```

You can do this with the following extension:

```
// works with NSAttributedString and NSMutableAttributedString!
public extension NSAttributedString {
    static func + (left: NSAttributedString, right: NSAttributedString) -> NSAttributedString {
        let leftCopy = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: left)
        leftCopy.append(right)
        return leftCopy
    }
    
    static func + (left: NSAttributedString, right: String) -> NSAttributedString {
        let leftCopy = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: left)
        let rightAttr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: right)
        leftCopy.append(rightAttr)
        return leftCopy
    }
    
    static func + (left: String, right: NSAttributedString) -> NSAttributedString {
        let leftAttr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: left)
        leftAttr.append(right)
        return leftAttr
    }
}

public extension NSMutableAttributedString {
    static func += (left: NSMutableAttributedString, right: String) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
        let rightAttr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: right)
        left.append(rightAttr)
        return left
    }
    
    static func += (left: NSMutableAttributedString, right: NSAttributedString) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
        left.append(right)
        return left
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using Swift 5.1 and I can't seem to just add two NSAttrStrings together...

Comment: Strange. In this case just use `NSAttrStr1.append(NSAttrStr2)`

Comment: Updated my answer with extensions for just adding two NSAttrStrings :)

Comment: Using Swift 5 joinWith didn't seem to work...ended up using append method.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Cocoapods, an alternative to both above answers that let you avoid mutability in your own code is to use the excellent [NSAttributedString+CCLFormat](https://github.com/cocodelabs/NSAttributedString-CCLFormat) category on `NSAttributedString`s that lets you write something like:

```
NSAttributedString *first = ...;
NSAttributedString *second = ...;
NSAttributedString *combined = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithFormat:@"%@%@", first, second];
```

It of course it just uses `NSMutableAttributedString` under the covers.

It also has the extra advantage of being a fully fledged formatting function — so it can do a lot more than appending strings together.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Immutable approach
// class method

+ (NSAttributedString *)stringByAppendingString:(NSAttributedString *)append toString:(NSAttributedString *)string {
  NSMutableAttributedString *result = [string mutableCopy];
  [result appendAttributedString:append];
  NSAttributedString *copy = [result copy];
  return copy;
}

//Instance method
- (NSAttributedString *)stringByAppendingString:(NSAttributedString *)append {
  NSMutableAttributedString *result = [self mutableCopy];
  [result appendAttributedString:append];
  NSAttributedString *copy = [result copy];
  return copy;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [SwiftyFormat](https://github.com/Igor-Palaguta/SwiftyFormat)
It uses following syntax

```
let format = "#{{user}} mentioned you in a comment. #{{comment}}"
let message = NSAttributedString(format: format,
                                 attributes: commonAttributes,
                                 mapping: ["user": attributedName, "comment": attributedComment])
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate it more?How its will works?

Answer (score 0):

```
private var fillAttributes:[NSMutableAttributedString.Key : Any]? = nil

fontAttributes = [.foregroundColor : SKColor.red,
                  .strokeWidth : 0.0,
                  .font : CPFont(name: "Verdana-Bold",
                  .size : 50,]

fontAttributes.updateValue(SKColor.green, forKey: .foregroundColor)
```