# How to concate two NSAttributed String in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have Two NSAttributed String but when I concate like

self.label.text = attrStr1 + attrStr2 //gives error

```
     var attrStr1: NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(data: "
<b>Welcome</b>".dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding, 
allowLossyConversion: true)!,options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:
 NSHTMLTextDocumentType],documentAttributes: nil,error: nil)!

    var attrStr2: NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(data: "
<i>User</i>".dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding, 
allowLossyConversion: true)!,options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: 
NSHTMLTextDocumentType],documentAttributes: nil,error: nil)!
```

Also can we concate one NSAttributedString and another NSString?

Comment: Read the docs. You need NSMutableAttributedString and it has a method appendAttributedString. Not reading the docs is just lazy

Comment: attrStr1.appendAttributedString(attrStr2) tried but no luck

Comment: Yes, because NSAttributedString is not NSMutableAttributedString.

Comment: gives error "void is not convertible to "NSAttributedString" even i use NSMutableAttributedString

Comment: that's because the method doesn't return anything and you are trying to set a string using it. This method will mutate the string it is being called in. Show the code you used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
     var attrStr1: NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(data: "
<b>Welcome</b>".dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding, 
allowLossyConversion: true)!,options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:
 NSHTMLTextDocumentType],documentAttributes: nil,error: nil)!

    var attrStr2: NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(data: "
<i>User</i>".dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding, 
allowLossyConversion: true)!,options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: 
NSHTMLTextDocumentType],documentAttributes: nil,error: nil)!
```

Concatenate this strings :

```
var concate = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attrStr1)
concate.appendAttributedString(attrStr2)

self.label.text = concate
```

Answer (score 1):

**2020 | SWIFT 5.1:**
You're able to add 2 NSAttributedString this like:

```
let concatenated =  NSAttrStr1.append(NSAttrStr2)
```

Also there is exist another better answer on the same question here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60329354/4423545

Comment: Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to two 'NSAttributedString' operands

Comment: For apend the error is: Cannot convert value of type 'Void' to specified type 'NSMutableAttributedString'. I can't find the reason of these errors.

Comment: @shtefane this means that your NSAttrStr2 is void, but not NSMutableAttributedString