# Get the actual truncated string from label

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, string, uilabel

I have a `UILabel` with an attributed string, where the content text is e.g. `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`, and and the [`numberOfLines`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620539-numberoflines?language=objc) property is `2`. For this scenario the label displays as follows (truncating the tail of the string):

> abcdefghijkl
>
> mnopqrstu...

Is there a way to request displayed `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstu..."` string instead of the whole original one? The content is mixed with English, Chinese, emoji, etc...

Comment: What do you mean by "the whole original one"? What exactly do you get?

Comment: may be these would be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034174/how-do-i-concatenate-strings-in-swift, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31224293/how-to-concate-two-nsattributed-string-in-swift, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091233/swift-split-string-over-multiple-lines, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27083445/how-to-join-two-string-with-a-new-line-between-them