# how to append Attributed Text String with Attributed String in Swift

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring

I want to append an Attributed Text with another Attributed Text in Swift. Please provide any sample code for appending operation  of two attributed String in Swift.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I concatenate NSAttributedStrings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18518222/how-can-i-concatenate-nsattributedstrings)

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Use `NSMutableAttributedString` to achieve that.

### Example

#### Swift 5

```swift
let yourAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black, NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)]
let yourOtherAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red, NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25)]

let partOne = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "This is an example ", attributes: yourAttributes)
let partTwo = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "for the combination of Attributed String!", attributes: yourOtherAttributes)

partOne.append(partTwo)
```

#### Swift 3

```
let yourAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)]
let yourOtherAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25)]

let partOne = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "This is an example ", attributes: yourAttributes)
let partTwo = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "for the combination of Attributed String!", attributes: yourOtherAttributes)

let combination = NSMutableAttributedString()

combination.append(partOne)
combination.append(partTwo)
```

`combination` represents your final string which contains both formattings provided by `yourAttributes` and `yourOtherAttributes`

#### Even older

```
let yourAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)]
let yourOtherAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(25)]

let partOne = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "This is an example ", attributes: yourAttributes)
let partTwo = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "for the combination of Attributed String!", attributes: yourOtherAttributes)

let combination = NSMutableAttributedString()

combination.appendAttributedString(partOne)
combination.appendAttributedString(partTwo)
```

Comment: I was surprised to find that, still in Swift 3, it seems to be essential to initialize the NSMutableAttributedString empty in order to append to it.

Comment: I smell the sarcasm, but it is seriously strange that one cant just append partTwo to partOne without an empty initialized NSMAString....

Answer (score 20):

[@glace's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36468093/1107226), modified to avoid empty `NSMutableAttributedString` declaration. Valid in Swift 3.1:

```
let yourAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)]
let yourOtherAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(25)]

let partOne = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "This is an example ", attributes: yourAttributes)
let partTwo = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "for the combination of Attributed String!", attributes: yourOtherAttributes)

partOne.append(partTwo)
```

`partOne` is then your final string with all the attributes. No intermediate "combiner" necessary.

**Swift 4**

```
let yourAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.black, .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)]
let yourOtherAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.red, .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25)]

let partOne = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "This is an example ", attributes: yourAttributes)
let partTwo = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "for the combination of Attributed String!", attributes: yourOtherAttributes)

partOne.append(partTwo)
```

Comment: By the time of my answer, the empty declaration of the combiner was necessary. Im off from Swift since then, cant confirm if changes in Swift 3.1 are making this possible.

Answer (score 9):

## Swift 5

As per "glace" answer, I just update font attribute and swift version.

```
    let boldFontAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black, NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)]
    let normalFontAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.darkGray, NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)]
    let partOne = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "This is an example ", attributes: boldFontAttributes)
    let partTwo = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "for the combination of Attributed String!", attributes: normalFontAttributes)

    let combination = NSMutableAttributedString()
    
    combination.append(partOne)
    combination.append(partTwo)
    lblUserName.attributedText = combination
```

Answer (score 2):

using extension,

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString{
    func getAttributedStringByAppending(attributedString:NSMutableAttributedString) -> NSMutableAttributedString{
        let newAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
        newAttributedString.append(self)
        newAttributedString.append(attributedString)
        return newAttributedString
    }
}
```

Usage:
attributedString1, attributedString2 are two NSMutableAttributedString, then

```
let combinedAttributedString = attributedString1.getAttributedStringByAppending(attributedString: attributedString2)
```

Answer (score -2):

### Swift 5

You can create the different attributes:

```
let kString1Attributes = NSAttributedString.attributes(foregroundColor: UIColor.white)
let kString2Attributes = NSAttributedString.attributes(foregroundColor: UIColor.black)
```

Define your attributed strings:

```
let attrString1 = NSAttributedString(string: "my string" + " ",
                                     attributes: kString1Attributes)
let attrString2 = NSAttributedString(string: "string 2",
                                     attributes: kString2Attributes)
```

Include them in an array and combine them all together:

```
let combinedAttrString = [attrString1, attrString2].joined()
```

Comment: There is no joined().