# How do I combine two attributed strings into one UILabel?

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I have two attributed strings and I want to place them in one label, how would I do this?

```
let font = UIFont(name: "Hidden", size: 15)
    let addfont = UIFont(name: "Hidden", size: 15)
    var att = [NSFontAttributeName : font]
    let attrString = NSAttributedString(
        string: animalname[indexPath.row],
        attributes: NSDictionary(
            object: font!,
            forKey: NSFontAttributeName) as! [String : AnyObject])

    let attrStringAdd = NSAttributedString(
        string: animalloc[indexPath.row],
        attributes: NSDictionary(
            object: addfont!,
            forKey: NSFontAttributeName) as! [String : AnyObject])

    cell.animaltext.attributedText = attrString + attrStringAdd
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I concatenate NSAttributedStrings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18518222/how-can-i-concatenate-nsattributedstrings)

Answer (score 1):

1. Concatinated both the string.
2. Find range for string1 and string2.
3. Then for particular range of string apply desired attribute.
4. Now assign this attributed string to UILabel.