# Make phone call on iPhone and take user back to app? (UIWebView does it)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, deep-linking

I used this code to make phone call:

```
NSString *phoneNumber = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:mymobileNO.titleLabel.text];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
```

and when the call ends, it does not take user back to the app. However, if I show a website in UIWebView and there is a phone number in the website(ie UIWebView recognises it), and if I tap that phone number link to make phone call, I will be taken back to the app when the call finishes.

My preliminary thinking is that the UIWebView does something internally like a deep link to the Phone app then another deep link inside the deep link to take the user back to the app. But I'm not sure. Is there a way to implement this feature?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use the `telprompt` URL, not `tel`.

So:

```
NSString *phoneNumber = [@"telprompt://" stringByAppendingString:mymobileNO.titleLabel.text];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
```

This will also give the user a confirmation box before calling the number.

Edit:

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456395/dial-a-phone-number-using-ios) question covers the same issue.

**Edit 2:**

For those wondering if this URL will result in rejection from the App Store, the answer is generally no. The greater risk is that Apple will suddenly stop supporting the `telprompt` scheme. As explained by [this article](http://www.raizlabs.com/dev/2014/04/getting-the-best-behavior-from-phone-call-requests-using-tel-in-an-ios-app/), there is a slightly 'safer' way of implementing `telprompt` with `UIWebView` (which uses `telprompt` internally, even if you call it with `tel`). The relevant code from the article shows how using the documented `tel` scheme can still give you the effect of `telprompt`:

```
+ (void)callWithString:(NSString *)phoneString {
    [self callWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString     
        stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",phoneString]]];
}

+ (void)callWithURL:(NSURL *)url {
    static UIWebView *webView = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{  
        webView = [UIWebView new];
    });
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
}
```

(Code taken from the article reference in my second edit)

Comment: Yes, but once the user makes the call, and the call finishes, can you take the user back to the app?

Comment: This URL prompt does that automatically.

Comment: But in the link you provided, looks like it is a private protocol and the app will be rejected if you use it.

Comment: @Rickay does apple approves it ?

Answer (score 0):

The website: http://www.raizlabs.com/dev/2014/04/getting-the-best-behavior-from-phone-call-requests-using-tel-in-an-ios-app/ has a discussion of whether to use telprompt (undocumented, Apple could potentially change the API without notice), and instead using a category that sends the number to a web view which opens it using telprompt. This has the advantage of not breaking if Apple does something odd.