# How to make a call and after disconnecting call want to back in view

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make phone call on iPhone and take user back to app? (UIWebView does it)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065498/make-phone-call-on-iphone-and-take-user-back-to-app-uiwebview-does-it)

I have an UITableView in tableview cell,there have a phone number.After selecting cell,want to make a call and after disconnected call from both side(dialer and receiver)want to back in my apps view.How its possible.Please help me.Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
-(void)makeACall:(NSString *)strContactNumber
{   
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];    
    NSString *ph_no = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",strContactNumber];    
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ph_no]]];
}
```

Comment: After disconnected from Receiver end thats not return on my apps View. Please help me.

Comment: I give you link...check it @iphone_Kanta.

Comment: It works fine for me, if not helps then another option which @Vishal shared a link.

Comment: @Vishal actually I m facing same problem & by doing above code it works fine. Thanks for upvote.

Comment: Really? Ok I  also try your code then give you feedback girish...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;
        if([deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPhone"])
        {
            NSString *phoneNumber = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:@"8437327307"];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *device = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ipod" message:@"Can't Call from this device" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [device show];
            [device release];
        }
```

Comment: In place of my no. you can add your no. static or dynamic...

Comment: Thanks Vishal. I have tried with this code but,thats back in contactView not in my apps view.Please help me.

Comment: See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065498/make-phone-call-on-iphone-and-take-user-back-to-app-uiwebview-does-it

Comment: Go through this link hope it solve your problem...

Comment: Thats not working in my Apps.Same problem is occurred.