# auto dial, iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am trying to make a program, in which, user can auto dial the number(last call preferably),similar to what we have in old telephone.

I need to get the last dial number from the call list and on one touch, user can make a call on that number.

Please guide me to get the idea, to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: That's easy. But you need to do it on a jailbroken device

Comment: yes, i am looking for jailbroken phone also.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify Phone app's logic. You can't.

Comment: +1 and Apple wouldn't allow an app like this to go onto the app store.  If your app can get the last phone number dialed, then other apps can maliciously log and/or transmit all the logged numbers somewhere off phone (i.e. big security risk).

Answer (score 0):

from
[Programmatically Dial a Phone number and pass DTMF using the iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584663/programatically-dial-a-phone-number-and-pass-dtmf-using-the-iphone-sdk)

Somehow helpful:

---

> I dont know why everyone says you cant... you CAN!
>
> NSString *phoneNumber = @"15555551212"; NSString *dtmfAfterPickup =
>   @"1234"; NSString *telString = [NSString
>   stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@,%@", phoneNumber, dtmfAfterPickup];
>   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL
>   URLWithString:telString]];

This will dial the phoneNumber bypassing the dial/cancel prompt... 1 second after the call is answered, the dtmfAfterPickup string will be automatically dialed.

Its a good idea to detect whether or not the device support phone calls

Comment: Did you try ? You can dial the number, but you cannot access the phone history. You can't make a phone app replacing the original one as well; it violates App Store Submission rule.